# Tracking down French birth certificate

Tags: france, birth-certificate

I leave abroad and I want to have my French citizenship recognized. The consulate asked me to produce my father's birth certificate. For that, I need his father's name. Does anybody here know what can be done?

- I dont have any connection with my father today
- I do know his full name and date of birth
- I also know my grandmother full name.

Comment: I am not sure I see the expatriation aspect. Where do you live? Where were you born? And what about your father?

Comment: Hi, Actually i do have french citizenship but now for getting a passport they ask me in consulate to get my father birth certificate. I had it once when i applied for citizenship but i didn't took a photo of it so now i need it again. my father left us when i was abuot 3 years old so i don't have any connection with him. when i applied for citizenship my cousins helped me with his birth certificate but know we didn't kept in touch.       did i explained myself enough? thanks! and best wishes,Etay

Comment: I don't think you ever applied for citizenship, otherwise there would be a *décret de naturalisation* and the rest would be moot. Based on what you said, it seems you are trying to establish is that you are French by descent, which is what I gathered from your original question but that does not answer my request for additional information. Unfortunately, I won't be able to provide a full answer but I know the procedure you have to follow depends on a person's place of birth, that's why I asked you to add that to your question.

Comment: Also, once you have solved your birth certificate problem, you should probably apply for a [*Certificat de nationalité française*](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/F1051.xhtml), that's the strongest form of evidence of your citizenship and would make formalities much easier going forward.

Comment: Finally, this site is intended to be about expatriation. [Questions everyone might face in a country are in principle off-topic](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I suspect you are having extra difficulties establishing your citizenship because you live abroad but it would be useful to specify that to make sure nobody closes the question.

Comment: Gala, maybe my first question is not in the place. Google navigated me here :-) I have a document from french consulate indicating my citizenship (i can send it to you). I was born in Israel.

Comment: The problem here is that OP does not know his grandfather's full name (it's a problem because in order to obtain a *copie intégrale* of a person's birth certificate, you must give their parents' names). The person's place of birth makes no difference in this regard.

Comment: @fkraiem I know that but where you should ask for a certificate (and consequently what other alternatives might be available or even how strict they are with the rules) does depend on that so the information should be in the question nonetheless.

Comment: @EtayLavert I must say I don't understand why the consulate wants your father's birth certificate if they are satisfied of your citizenship.

Comment: @EtayLavert I added the info you provided to your question, I hope it's OK.